# Find repetitive patterns in matrices below

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, pattern-recognition, filter

How can I identify the repetitive patterns from the matrices below? My problem is that the patterns in the matrix are different from matrix to matrix (dependent on the input data). I need some machine learning technique that detects these square like patterns at each position really accurately. Hence I believe that using a lowpass filter to reduce the noise in the pattern would be counter productive. I am pretty good in image processing, but here I am quite lost. Any suggestion is appreciated.
The matrices below are different and display the variation in the patterns. Red is low values and white / blue are high values. I used the RdBu  [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) for plotting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Run spectral analysis, find the base frequency, that'll give you the size of your repetitive block.

Comment: There is a [signal processing SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) - would that be more appropriate than than the stats SE for a question like this?